# How to replace \varnothing by \phi

Tags: math-mode

I have written `\varnothing` in place of `\phi` everywhere in my thesis. Now, I want to change it by `\phi`. So, does there any technique so that I change at only one place and it changes everywhere ?

Comment: Search and replace? Or (not really recommended) `\renewcommand{\varnothing}{\phi}` -- It is usually better to provide markup wrappers for such symbols/constructs to use it later in the document and change the wrapper's definition, if needed

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was writing the exact same comment.

Comment: @crixstox: Apparently you have deleted it? Normally, there's no need to do so.

Comment: Search and replace: using the correct semantics is important.

Answer (score 4):

If you write
`\let\varnothing\varphi`
in the preamble then TeX will grab the variable phi symbol instead of the stroked zero symbol.  See Christian's answer on how to avoid this situation in the future.

Answer (score 2):

With some experience in writing thesis or articles etc. it's quite natural to have logical markup, i.e. use a command that does all the typesetting of certain symbols or constructs and it will look all the same throughout the document -- this guarantees consistent look (at least for such symbols).

A design change just involves changing the wrapper/markup command, not a tedious looking where a certain symbol has been used and replacing it by hand.

However, unfortunately the `\varnothing` command (most probably th ewrong symbol for the purpose of the O.P.) has been used, it must be replaced with the wrapper by a `Search-And-Replace` method using the features of the editor (xemacs/vi/TeXMaker etc.) -- replace it with the wrapper, say, `\phisymbol` and define

```
\newcommand{\phisymbol}{\phi}.
```

Here's redefinition later on to show the versatility of the markup approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\phisymbol}{\varnothing}

\begin{document}


Here is my symbol $\phisymbol$ which I want to change.


\renewcommand{\phisymbol}{\phi}

Now it is changed: $\phisymbol$

\end{document}
```

[image]